# Is the order of importing tensorflow and torch relevant?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I am using a PyTorch model to run inference on an image, using a standard CNN model.

I have noticed that the order in which I import the `tensorflow` and the `torch` packages has an effect on the time the inference is taking.

When importing `tensorflow` first, the inference takes ~200ms. When importing it after `torch`, the inference time increases up to 800ms.

```
# import tensorflow # <-- model inference takes 200ms
import torch
# import tensorflow # <-- model inference takes 800ms
```

The inference also takes 800ms when `tensorflow` is not imported add all.

Coming from other programming languages, I assume that the import of the `tensorflow` package has side effects which affect what the `torch` import does. Is this assumption correct?

My notebook is running in the context of a custom Docker container based on `nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:22.09-tf2-py3`. In addition, these packages were installed `pip install torch==1.12.1+cu113 torchaudio==0.12.1+cu113 torchvision==0.13.1+cu113 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113`

Update: What is really confusing about this is that the `tensorflow` package is not even used in my code. I simply had it left in my notebook. When I noticed that, I removed the import, which changed the inference duration.

Is this a known behaviour?

Comment: Why would you need Tensorflow _and_ Torch in the same process?

Comment: Interestingly, the import time is different too, `python -c "import torch; import tensorflow"` is about 15% faster than `python -c "import tensorflow; import torch"`. I was playing with running those two commands with `PYTHONPROFILEIMPORTTIME=1` to see if the order changed what actually got imported deep down, but it seems like it did not.

Comment: I do not, in fact. That is what is really confusing me. Simply having the import speeds up the inference. I am sure that this is not "magic" but some side effect of the import. Does the tensorflow package register / setup some global state which changes how Torch behaves?

Comment: would you mind to add a timing WITHOUT tensorflow? I assume its the other way around: Importing it first does no harm, importing it later does harm. So "its not harming" not "improving", correct?

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't explicit enough i think. The timings are the same when tensorflow is not imported and when it is imported after torch.

Comment: so everything else the same, importing tensorflow increases the speed in your case... well, thats indeed interesting...

Answer (score 1):

A common "problem" of importing tensorflow is that it tries to occupy as much GPU memory as it can get. This is something you can turn off manually as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57992246/9659620).

Being restricted in memory might leave the dataloader unable to pin gpu mem for faster access and training would be slower.  Since you have inference here, it is not clear to me how this could effect your inference speed, to be honest. But still, such connection seems plausible to me.

I hope this info useful as you further try to understand the situation.

Also, are you sure that your time measurement is accurate?

Note: It might be better to not import tensorflow at all. For example, tools like tensorboard are also available in pytorch directly and you dont get any interference!

Comment: I am sure that the measurement is correct. In fact, the tensorflow package is not even used. I will add that to the question, sorry that I forgot to mention.